# Quick blox android SDk

Tags: android, push-notification, quickblox

I am facing a problem in quickblox android sdk

1. When we are doing one to one chat it works fine; but during chat if accidentally internet connection gets lost and again it gets connected; in that case we should get push notification.

But we don't get push notification for all messages received during that duration. Push notification gets received only when we successfully logout from QB otherwise it does not. If accidentally internet is lost; then we are unable to logout from QB and hence the result no push notification is received.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once the internet connection is lost, the server still thinks that you are still online for some time (minute or so), so in this case push notification can not be sent instantly after internet connection is lost. To minimise the loss of messages in such cases it is recommended to use Stream management:
1) Android SDK 2.4 Beta with Stream Management https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/development2.3/jars

2) How to use samples:
- enabling SM: https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/blob/development2.3/snippets/src/com/sdk/snippets/modules/SnippetsChat.java#L244
- call-backs: https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/blob/development2.3/snippets/src/com/sdk/snippets/modules/SnippetsChat.java#L250
- using call-backs
https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/blob/development2.3/snippets/src/com/sdk/snippets/modules/SnippetsChat.java#L307
https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/blob/development2.3/snippets/src/com/sdk/snippets/modules/SnippetsChat.java#L920

3) This SDK version has  API-breaking changes

Full changelog (additional changes can be added to release version)
 - QBEntityCallbackImpl class is deprecated. Use QBEntityCallback now
 - QBEntityCallback now contains only 2 methods
 -  QBEntityCallback.onError now gives QBResponceException instead of List
 - TransferProtocol class is removed. 
   Now you should provide an URL with https here
   QBSettings.getInstance().setServerApiDomain("https://api.quickblox.com"); if you use custom endpoints
 - Removed deprecated methods of 1.x API
 - Renamed all setters and getters to correct meaning in QBLimitedRequestBuilder
-  Removed Ratings API

Comment: I have also implemented these stream management & upgraded sdk but no benifits.